# Responsive Template Issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template, design

We've been working on responsive email templates in Marketo, Mail Chimp, Campaign Monitor, and a variety of other products for some time now.

All have their perks and issues, but we've encountered a significant issue in ET that we're unable to resolve.

We're using a responsive template in ET with  tags (so our non-HTML savvy clients can quickly add pre-built areas of content), and are finding that ET is generating two extra HTML tables around each generated custom content area, as well as some unwanted  styling.

These extra tables are breaking the carefully designed email template, and make the building of a responsive template very difficult.

Please let us know what we can do:

- Is there a way that we can disable this?
- Can we turn it off at a system-level per-client?
- Or, has anyone else come across and resolved this issue?

Comment: Can you describe your specific method of creating your template within ET?

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately how ET fills the template in its UI. I have not found a solution outside building the template with those tables in mind. Using AMPscript works much better, and does not add extra HTML, but requires more work and makes it harder to have non-savvy people use it. The new template language (guide template language or something like that) they are implementing seems like it will solve the issue. Maybe will be solved with Content Builder/Content Canvas.  Sorry can't be more help.

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding the HTML into the content area are you selecting HTML or Free Form as the content area type?

If you select the HTML option for your content block it can sometimes add extra HTML.

Try using Free Form as this will only include the HTML you paste into the content area.

Comment: Free Form has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting HTML as your content area type seems to work.

Comment: Hi there,

That's great, but our client's aren't all HTML savvy - definitely a good solution for those that are though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy, for every free form content block nest everything in the table and control your responsive rules from there.

Unfortunately, this will be the same in Content Builder for free form content blocks.